# How can I align decimal points in a datatable?

Tags: flutter, datatable, alignment, decimal

Values are centered:

[image]

I need them to be centered with respect to the decimal point:

[image]

Is it possible to center a text with respect to a certain character?

Inside my `DataTable` I have my `DataColumns` and my `Datacels`, and inside the latter I have an `Align` with a `Text`. That align does not center the way I want.

```dart
return DataCell(
      Align(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: Text(
          datos,
          style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: style.Colors.lightColor),
        ),
      ),
    );
```